# Task optimization algorithm

Tags: php, optimization, task

I have a resource optimization tasks how to organize the work of several users on dynamic tasks.

Here is the entity structure:
There are several projects
`Projects{id,name}`

Each day there are several task packages:
`Package{id,name, project_id,arrival_date, deadline_date}`
`Task{id,package_id,content, estimated_time}`

The users have different skill level and approval for each project:
`User{id, name}`
`User2Projects{id, user_id, project_id, speed, priority}`
`UsersDayPlan{id, user_id, date, from_time, to_time}`

The goal is to build a application/ algorithm to optimize the tasks distribute between
all the users, so that every package is done before the deadline (or as close as posible).

**EDIT:**
I see several constrains rules here:
 1. task should go to people with approval for the project and with the highest skill level possible.
 2. IF package is close to its deadline, more users should be allocated ignoring rule 1.

So I'm looking for directions and tools.

It looks to me as a "classical" Math problem and there should be some algorithms for this type of tasks.

Any libraries or tools will be appreciated.

The result application will probably be web based using PHP so related technology are prefered.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually a very common problem, and a variation on the [0/1 Knapsack Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). Actually, the optimal solution is to only do parts of tasks, but when you do not have that option, you can employ some greedy strategies. One method that yields good results is to start with the shortest task, right up until the longest task. Look at it like this:

```
Task1 duration = 10
Task2 duration = 20
Task3 duration = 30
```

We start with `Task1`, meaning that `Task1` is done in 10 minutes, and all other tasks get 10 added to them.

```
Current Total time: Task1(10) + (10 + Task2) + (10 + Task2 + Task3)
```

As you can see, as you complete one task, all other tasks must wait the required amount of time, or:

```
TaskN = TaskN-1 + TaskN.
```

From this then, you want to have the lowest values repeating. So you start off with the smallest, to ensure the minimal waiting time for all other tasks.

Comment: I was thinking also for the Knapsack Problem. Bit here we have many users that work simultaneously and the have different skill level for each task/project .. so the variables become to many for just linear sorting.

Comment: you're saying that some people have more priority than others?

Comment: yes @Chris  tasks are separated by project, and each user has approval only for some of the projects, and different skill level on each project (some users can do single task on project A 2 times faster then other user). see the `User2Project` Entity